# Where did I go wrong commenting on this post?

Tags: discussion

[https://superuser.com/questions/1192219/graphics-requirement-for-adobe-premier-pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1192219/graphics-requirement-for-adobe-premier-pro/1192222#1192222)

The user asked for Adobe Premiere' graphics requirements, to which I supplied a link. Adobe product users know that it can be frustrating to find needed information on the Adobe site and sometimes information seems to be hiding in plain sight.

I did not recommend hardware, but provided the term needed (benchmark) for a useful web search and an example link to a web page that would be the type of page to look for to answer, with a caution to use judgement.

Did I go wrong responding to the question at all? Downvotes burn and I thought I was being helpful.

Comment: Comments should not be used to answer a question.  So if your answer was a comment, it shouldn't have been submitted, doesn't mean the question doesn't have an answer.  But in this case, the question should be improved, before its answered

Comment: One point that hasn't been explicitly said, you **can** use a comment to post helpful hints and links (they aren't just for requesting clarification).  That would have been the best place for it.  What you want to avoid in that direction is posting a complete, definitive solution as a comment.  Those should be an answer because comments are transient, can't be searched, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Link only answers are generally [not appreciated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) on the Stack Exchange network.

> **When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.**

We prefer answers to state the important information and use links for citation only.

For you it would have been good to copy the relevant specifications and given the link for reference.  Bonus points for saying *why* the specifications are needed or important.

The question itself is though is incredibly low quality and could have easily been answered by Google.

Comment: I understand and have read that answers should not be link only. However, I thought that comments were the way to ask for clarification or to provide general help, which is what I thought I was doing and is what I have seen others do.

Comment: @Imagenotavailable comments and answers *are* different. In order to add a comment on the question you need to click the "add a comment" link which will open a box below the question but above the answer area. You posted an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Aha! For some reason I remembered only commenting. I definitely need to get some sleep. I deleted my "answer" and accept the shame.

Comment: @Imagenotavailable if you need clarification and can't post a comment don't try and answer the question.  It's just that simple.  Even if you were to quote the relevant information you were unable to answer them author's followup questions which were not difficult.  Basically trying to say, you attempted to and a question, you didn't know the answer to.  Focus on answering questions that are clear and you know the answer to.

Answer (score 3):

#### Did I go wrong responding to the question at all?

1. You answered a very poor question - the OP has clearly done no research at all.
2. You provided a link only answer. Please read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

   If the link is removed then all that is left is:

   > Adobe Premiere hardware requirements

   which doesn't give an useful information at all.

   My standard comment to such an answer is:

   > Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.
3. You have added additional useful information in a comment to your own answer. It would be better if this information was **in the answer itself**

Comment: Sorry, as I responded to @mokubai, I thought comments and answers were more different than they appear to be.